# Is there a way to customize the keys in tmux's "choose mode"?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

From [tmux's manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#WINDOWS_AND_PANES)

> ```
>       -   Choose mode, which allows an item to be chosen from a
>           list.  This may be a client, a session or window or pane,
>           or a buffer.  This mode is entered with the
>           choose-buffer, choose-client and choose-tree commands.
> ```

And if we look at the `choose-tree` command:

```
The following keys may be used in tree mode:

                   Key    Function
                   Enter  Choose selected item
                   Up     Select previous item
                   Down   Select next item
                   +      Expand selected item
                   -      Collapse selected item
                   M-+    Expand all items
                   M--    Collapse all items
                   x      Kill selected item
                   X      Kill tagged items
                   <      Scroll list of previews left
                   >      Scroll list of previews right
                   C-s    Search by name
                   m      Set the marked pane
                   M      Clear the marked pane
                   n      Repeat last search
                   t      Toggle if item is tagged
                   T      Tag no items
                   C-t    Tag all items
                   :      Run a command for each tagged item
                   f      Enter a format to filter items
                   H      Jump to the starting pane
                   O      Change sort field
                   r      Reverse sort order
                   v      Toggle preview
                   q      Exit mode
```

Specifically, I'd like to also bind `C-c` to `Exit mode`, just like `q` already is.

Unlike copy-mode, copy-mode-vi and root, there is no keytable for this so-called "choose mode". So is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Specifically, I'd like to also bind `C-c` to `Exit mode`, just like `q` already is.

It appears that in a mode (other than `copy-mode`*) the `root` key table is relevant; plus the keys specific to the mode (like what you cited in the question), but the `root` key table is applied first.

This means if we make the `root` key table convert `C-c` to `q` when in the mode then the mode will react to our <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> like it reacts to <kbd>q</kbd>.

We can convert `C-c` to `q` conditionally. This is a line for `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key -T root C-c if-shell -F '#{==:#{pane_mode},tree-mode}' 'send-keys q' 'send-keys C-c'
```

Keep in mind the file is parsed when a tmux server starts. To affect our already running server we need to pass the command to tmux (e.g. `tmux bind-key …` in a shell inside tmux) or to reload the altered file (<kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`source-file ~/.tmux.conf`<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> the binding detects if the current pane is in the `tree-mode` (`-F '#{==:#{pane_mode},tree-mode}'`). If so, it sends `q` (`send-keys q`); if not, it sends `C-c` (`send-keys C-c`) as we do not want to lose the functionality of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> when not in the mode.

To learn the formal name of another mode we can do this:

1. In a shell in a pane we invoke `echo "$TMUX_PANE"`. Suppose the output is `%0`.
2. We put the pane in the desired mode.
3. In a shell in another pane we invoke `tmux display-message -t %0 -p '#{pane_mode}'`, where `%0` is the output from the step 1.

I have identified `view-mode`, `tree-mode`, `client-mode`, `buffer-mode`, `options-mode`, `clock-mode` and `copy-mode` (which stands out in the context of your question, see the footnote*). There may be others.

To detect more than one mode we need some logic. Example:

```
bind-key -T root C-c if-shell -F '#{m/r:(tree|client|buffer)-mode,#{pane_mode}}' 'send-keys q' 'send-keys C-c'
```

If we want to convert `C-c` to `q` in all modes*, we use the following line instead:

```
bind-key -T root C-c if-shell -F '#{pane_in_mode}' 'send-keys q' 'send-keys C-c'
```

---

<sup>* For `copy-mode` the `root` key table (`-T root`) seems irrelevant. As you noticed, a separate table `copy-mode` (or `copy-mode-vi`) is used in the copy mode.</sup>